# Sorting a Listbox in C++

Tags: string, forms, sorting, c++-cli

first time asking questions here. I'm having trouble sorting a listbox in a c++ form. I would much rather do this in C# but it's a class requirement unfortunately. Here's the code in question:

```
void updateCourseDisplay()
{  
    courseListBox->Items->Clear();
    set<Course*> courseSet = courseControl->getCourseSet();
    std::set<Course *>::iterator it;
    for (it = courseSet.begin(); it != courseSet.end(); ++it)
    {
        Course * c = (*it);

        String ^courseId = gcnew String((c->getID().c_str()));
        String ^courseName = gcnew String((c->getName().c_str()));

        courseListBox->Items->Add(courseId + " - " + courseName);
    }
    courseListBox->System::Windows::Forms::ListBox::Sort();

    populateCopyStudentsComboBox();
}
```

I know this is pretty messy but I didn't want to mess around with creating managed objects to add to the form. The error I'm getting when I try and run this says that System::Windows::Forms::ListBox::Sort() would have been called but it is inaccessible. All I want is simple ordering of the list by the string value. Any thoughts?

Comment: That's not C++, but C++CLI

Comment: Do not use native C++ in C++/CLI. Change `set` to [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx), [SortedSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx). Use `foreach` instead of `for` and `iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

`Sort` is a protected method that can not be accessed from the "outside". You should set the public `Sorted` property to true instead.

Comment: Thanks! Easy as that and it works. Appreciate the help.